# A few questions about the Inverse Galois Problem

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Here are some musings I've had about the Inverse Galois Problem, which I'm curious as to what thoughts have been given to them. I know only a little of Galois theory so forgive me if these are just plain wrong, or evident results.

Let $G = \textbf{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$, and assume that $G$ has a nontrivial finite subgroup $H$ (do we even know if such an $H$ exists?).

> Is $H$ the Galois group of a polynomial?

The converse question is also interesting.

> If $K$ is the Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ of a polynomial, is it a subgroup of $G$?

Furthermore, and I'm not sure how to properly phrase this, if $g$ is an element of $K$, can it be extended to an element of $G$? In the sense that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial such that $K$ is its Galois group, and $\hat{g}$ is the extended element, $\hat{g}$ acts on the roots of $f(x)$ just like $g$.

If the first question is true, then the Inverse Galois Problem could be reformulated as showing that every finite group is a subgroup of $G$. Does any of these questions make any sense? I guess this approach won't really do much since we don't really know anything about the structure of $G$.

Comment: Why do you care of the finite subgroups of $G $ ? The finite extensions correspond to the finite index subgroups, through $K \to Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/K)$

Comment: I'm mostly clueless, I was just curious about them, hoping there was some relationship between them and Galois groups of polynomials.

Comment: A polynomial $\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ corresponds to its splitting field $L$ which corresponds to $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})=G/H$ ($L$ corresponds to the map $G\to G/H$, not the abstract group $G/H$) where $H=Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/L)$ is a finite index normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: That I realize. I guess the idea I had was that given a finite subgroup $H$ of $G$, I was thinking that its elements would act on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ just like elements of a finite Galois group of a polynomial.